# Split Multi Scrolling middle of the page with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, reactjs

I want to add multiscroller in my site same as it is in the following examle:
https://www.uber.com
[image: Example ScreenShort]
Where the div in the middle remains fixed and the content scrolls untill content gets to an end,  when content gets to an end page scrolls to next section.
I searched on google but hard to find the required solution.
Here is one example I got but it is full screen and doesn't work on middle of the page:
http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/